# Motives in tropical geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motives, tropical-geometry, tate-motives

Is there a notion of motives in tropical geometry? Similar like the notion introduced by `Grothendieck`  in algebraic geometry.